# Select multiple extreme values in a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a context in which I have multiple processes applied to objects. So I have a `process` table and an `object` table. For example, the processes might relate to medication, and the objects might be animals because I'm a vet in a zoo.

I want to hide my queries behind a graphical UI that allows me to easily switch between viewing all processes for all objects one moment; then filter down to certain objects/processes a moment later (easy: just add/remove a WHERE clause); and to pinpoint extreme values (e.g. first/last in sequence of processes, or earliest/latest process) a moment later again. I'd **really** like to do this in a `WHERE` clause because switching it in/out becomes much easier. Is this possible?

Using the zoo example, I may have a query joining my two tables that yields:

```
obj.name  proc.type    proc.num     proc.date
========  =========    =========    =========
 tiger     this         1           2020/12/18
 tiger     this         2           2021/01/05
 tiger     that         1           2020/11/22
 tiger     that         2           2020/12/18
 tiger     that         3           2021/01/05
 tiger     other        1           2021/01/12
 lion      this         1           2020/11/18
 lion      other        1           2020/12/05
 lion      other        2           2021/02/21
 lion      that         1           2021/02/09
```

You can imagine it is easy to add (for example) `WHERE obj.name='lion'` or `WHERE proc.type='that'` to filter this query down to specify objects or processes. But what I want is to filter on extreme values of the `proc.num` or `proc.date` columns to get results like this (e.g. to answer questions such as "what is the last treatment each animal had for each condition?"):

```
obj.name  proc.type    proc.num     proc.date
========  =========    =========    =========
 tiger     this         2           2021/01/05
 tiger     that         3           2021/01/05
 tiger     other        1           2021/01/12
 lion      this         1           2020/11/18
 lion      other        2           2021/02/21
 lion      that         1           2021/02/09
```

The question is: can I add only a `WHERE` clause to identify extreme values? Or do I have to also switch in a `GROUP BY` clause to achieve such results?

Comment: When adding the SQL tag, it is almost always necessary to include a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as functionality and syntax varies widely between them. Please [edit] your post to include that tag.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your are using Postgres, you may use a single pass query with `DISTINCT ON`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (obj.name, proc.type) *
FROM obj
INNER JOIN proc
    ON <join conditions>
WHERE ...
ORDER BY obj.name, proc.type, proc.date DESC;
```

Note that my initial answer mentioned that you would need to use a subquery along with an analytic function such as `ROW_NUMBER`.  This would usually be the case with most databases, but in this case Postgres has `DISTINCT ON`, which lets us avoid an explicit subquery.

Comment: Doesn't quite answer my question directly - it's not a query modified by simply adding a `WHERE` clause; instead it takes the query and wraps it in an interesting/informative way. If it is definitively not going to be possible to do this within a self-contained `WHERE` clause (e.g. because extra grouping/partitioning/etc functionality is required outside that clause to support the aggregation) feel free to edit in a sentence explaining that, and I'll accept the answer :-)

Comment: @omatai Two comments: 1) _Always_ tag your exact database when posting a question here, and 2) given that you're on Postgres, I think `DISTINCT ON` can work here.  But usually, you do need a subquery for your requirement.